# Expected value of brownian motion for all positive paths

Tags: brownian-motion

I've got this question but I can't figure it out.

> Derive the expected value of $B(t_1)$ of all paths that are positive $t_1$ and calculate the expectation for $t_1=1$ and variance$=1$?

Thanks

Comment: $B(t_1)$ is normally distributed.